# Text content overflow to new dynamic column on lower window heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

How do I go about getting text content to carryover to a dynamically created column to it's right when the window height is reduced? 

Basically this: 
[image]

Is there any jquery/other plugins out there that can do this?

I hit the wall while working on a horizontally scrolling website, and this has been haunting me and driving me crazy for the past month. I guess, the madness had clogged my mind to allow proper research. 
There's treesaver.js http://demo.nomadeditions.com/wide-screen/#-/wide-screen/oscar-bloggers.html; it works fine in IE9, but wouldn't even load in IE8 (I checked on IEtester so chances are it could be incorrect). The only problem I have with treesaver is it's constant re-loading whenever the window's resized but that's just a pet peeve.
It would be nice if this can be done in css itself; this trivial issue really shouldn't need a javascript plugin, but the wide array of browsers(along with their own quirkiness') used in the market forces me to dip my hand in the js basket first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is currently a W3C candidate reccomendation

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

You can see it in action here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

The bad news is it's not supported by IE 8 even in standards mode. I don't have IE 9 available here, but if this is a public site, you probably can't require IE 9 yet anyway.

Comment: Hey Gus, thanks for the input. I'd considered multi-columns, but couldn't go far with it either.
Height didn't affect the column count when I used it(I may have done something wrong), anyways, I was not aware of "break-after: column" and "overflow: visible" which looks interesting. Dabbling with it right now.

Comment: **update** http://jsbin.com/icorub/2/edit#html,live Got it working mate! _(ironically, I didn't have to use either break-after or overflow: visible)_ :] The code's not very refined, but still gives a basic idea. Cheers all round!
As for IE users, they'll see a gracefully degraded vertically scrolling website.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the text effects in http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/

Comment: I don't think this would work. I'm also not that handy with js, so if it indeed can be done with this plugin I'd appreciate a jsfiddle if it's not asking too much.